# PS Script save location

Tags: powershell

I am trying to save this to a .csv on my laptop

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90 | Get-ADUser -1 Properties Name, sAMAccountName, givenName, sn, userAccountControl | Where {($_.userAccountControl -band 2) -eq $False} | Select Name, sAMAccountName, givenName, sn | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\ExportTest.csv
```

the scripts runs as needed, This part does not run:

```
| Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\ExportTest.csv
```

Comment: Have you got UAC enabled?  Is PowerShell running as an Administrator? What happens if you change it to `Export-Csv -Path "${env:USERPROFILE}\Desktop" -NoType`?  If that works then it's just filesystem permissions.

Comment: Do you get a error

Comment: UAC is turned down, PS running as admin. I tested your changes and it did not error out but also did not output a file.

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: no error with this but no output file either Export-Csv -Path "${env:USERPROFILE}\Desktop" -NoType? If that works then it's just filesystem permissions

Comment: Export-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ArgumentList'.
At line:1 char:294
+ ... | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\ExportTest.csv -ArgumentList
+                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: that is the error with the original script

Comment: if thats the error then ur not showing the correct code becuase your error is about -ArgumentList not being an accepted param for Export-CSV

Comment: sorry, I am new to this. here is the original script. now there are no errors but no output also.      Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90 | Get-ADUser -Properties Name, sAMAccountName, givenName, sn, userAccountControl | Where {($_.userAccountControl -band 2) -eq $False} | Select Name, sAMAccountName, givenName, sn | Export-CSV c:\ExportTest.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: the original script works not, not sure what changed. thank you all.

Comment: The code in the question calls `Get-ADUser` as `Get-ADUser -1 Properties Name,...` (incorrect) whereas the code in the answer calls it as `Get-ADUser -Properties Name,...` (correct).

Answer (score 0):

This script works to export inactive accounts to a .CSV file

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90 | 
Get-ADUser -Properties Name, sAMAccountName, givenName, sn, userAccountControl |
Where {($_.userAccountControl -band 2) -eq $False} |
Select Name, sAMAccountName, givenName, sn |
Export-CSV c:\YOURFOLDER\FILENAME.csv -NoTypeInformation
```